# VB.NET get file name of selected file in OpenFileDialog - no path

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I'm using the OpenFileDialog to open an Excel workbook, pass data from that workbook to another workbook, and then close the workbook I opened via OpenFileDialog. My problem is passing the data...how do I obtain just the name of the file I've opened via OpenFileDialog? I can't have the path, I just need the name of the file with it's extension. Here's part of my code

```
Dim filedialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
Dim strFileName As String
                filedialog.Title = "Open File Dialog"
                filedialog.InitialDirectory = "W:\TOM\ERIC\NET Dev"
                filedialog.RestoreDirectory = True
                If filedialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    strFileName = filedialog.FileName
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strFileName)
                    StatVar.xlApp.Workbooks(StatVar.workbookName).Sheets("Input Form     Info").Range("B4:B204").Value = StatVar.xlApp.Workbooks(strFileName).Sheets("DJA Corp     Use").Range("C2:C202").Value
                    StatVar.xlApp.Workbooks(strFileName).Close(False)
                End If
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
```

I can't pass my data from workbook to workbook because the strFileName variable contains the file path. I've been trying to work with this function to return the file name but I'm not experienced enough apparently. Any help is appreciated.

```
    Public Function FileNameWithoutPath(ByVal FullPath As String) As String

    Return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FullPath).ToString

    End Function
```

Comment: Don't make us guess! What *specifically* is wrong with the `FileNameWithoutPath` function that you have written?

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with the function, I'm just pretty new to programming and am not quite sure how to implement it with the OpenFileDialog method above

Comment: What about replacing the line `trFileName = filedialog.FileName` with `trFileName = FileNameWithoutPath(filedialog.FileName)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `filedialog.SafeFileName`

Gets the file name and extension for the file selected in the dialog box. The file name does not include the path.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to leave it as the full path for Process.Start(), then afterwards remove the path so it's just the filename:

```
            If filedialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                strFileName = filedialog.FileName
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strFileName)

                strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName)
                StatVar.xlApp.Workbooks(StatVar.workbookName).Sheets("Input Form     Info").Range("B4:B204").Value = StatVar.xlApp.Workbooks(strFileName).Sheets("DJA Corp     Use").Range("C2:C202").Value
                StatVar.xlApp.Workbooks(strFileName).Close(False)
            End If
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me an error: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)) on this line: StatVar.xlApp.Workbooks(StatVar.workbookName).Sheets("Input Form     Info").Range("B4:B204").Value = StatVar.xlApp.Workbooks(strFileName).Sheets("DJA Corp     Use").Range("C2:C202").Value
                StatVar.xlApp.Workbooks(strFileName).Close(False)
            End If

Comment: I don't work specifically with Excel, sorry.

Comment: Figured this out. It's because when I open the 2nd file through openfiledialog, it opens the xlsx file in a separate Excel process, thus preventing me from referencing it properly with my variables

Comment: To elaborate a further, earlier in my application I'm setting IgnoreRemoteRequests to True for my xlApp, if I set this to false before running the above code it will allow the file selected in openfiledialog to open in the Excel process I'm already running, thus allowing me to reference it via my xlApp variable

Answer (score 0):

Get the File Name of Open file Dialog then Use System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)